# indexeddb: How does changing the variable names during a request cause one to error?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm learning indexeddb and I got confused when comparing the 2 functions below. They are identical except that I changed the that last `request` variable names for code#2 to variable `request2` name. This causes them to yield different results.

code#1

```
function updateEntry(){
    var tx = db.transaction('practiceStore', 'readwrite');
    var store = tx.objectStore('practiceStore');
    var request = store.get(3);
    request.onsuccess = event => {
        console.log(request.result)
        let entry = request.result;
        
        entry.title = 'mdn way'
        var request = store.put(entry)
        request.onsuccess = event => {
            console.log('putting')
        }
    }
    tx.oncomplete = event => {
        console.log('tx complete')
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
errors
```

vs.

code#2

```
function updateEntry(){
    var tx = db.transaction('practiceStore', 'readwrite');
    var store = tx.objectStore('practiceStore');
    var request = store.get(3);
    request.onsuccess = event => {
        console.log(request.result)
        let entry = request.result;
        
        entry.title = 'mdn way'
        var request2 = store.put(entry)
        request2.onsuccess = event => {
            console.log('putting')
        }
    }
    tx.oncomplete = event => {
        console.log('tx complete')
    }
}
```

outputs

```
//does expected behavior
```

Code#1 errors on the line with `console.log(request.result)`. I tried using chrome devtools debugger and found that the debugger never makes it to `var request = store.put(entry)` which makes this even more confusing to me.

Code#1 errors because request is undefined. I conceptually don't understand how redefining `request` later changes anything. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Read up on `var`, `let` and `const`.

Comment: your kidding me, I realize now that having `var request` a second time is unnecessary. I just deleted the second `var` for `request` and it worked. However, I still don't understand how the second `var request` would affect code that happens before it especially when the debugger doesn't even reach it. My current understanding is that `var` functionally scoped. `let` is block scoped, and `const` you can't change it unless it is an object. Edit: @sheun helped, this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, I think this has to do with something called "hoisting" in javascript.

Basically, hoisting means that variable declarations in code are "brought to the top of the code". In the case of declaring AND initializing a variable, as you do with `var request = store.put(entry)` , the declaration (var request;) is hoisted to the top but not the initializaton (actually assigning the result of store.put).

Thus, when run your code#1 actually looks like this:

```
request.onsuccess = event => {
        var request; //this is the "hoisting" I am referring to
        console.log(request.result) //this is currently undefined now!
        let entry = request.result;
        
        entry.title = 'mdn way'
        request = store.put(entry) //this is the assignment
        request.onsuccess = event => {
            console.log('putting')
        }
    }
```

This is a bit confusing, but is explained well here (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp), especially the part about hoisting the declaration but NOT the initialization (see EXAMPLE 2 in the link).

When you change the name to request2, it similarly gets hoisted, but does NOT overwrite the outside request and thus request.result is not undefined.

Does that make sense?